# Change of variable in 2D integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

If I have an integral of the form

$$
I = \int_{-T}^T dx\int_{-T}^T dy\ i(x - y)
\tag1$$

Where $i$ is any function depending just on the relative variable, i.e., $x - y$. But, let's suppose that I need to perform the following change of variable:

$$
r = \frac{x + y}{2}, \quad R = x - y
\tag2$$

Then, I think that $I$ will become

$$
I = \int_{-\sqrt{2}T/2}^{\sqrt{2}T/2}dr \int_{-\sqrt{2}T}^{\sqrt{2}T}dR\ i(R)
\tag3$$

But I'm not sure. My reasoning to get this new limits is as follows: from Eq. (2), you can imagine $R$ as the module of a 2D vector in the cartesian plane, so

$$\vec{R}_{maximum} = (T, 0) - (0, T) \Rightarrow R_{maximum} = \sqrt{2}T$$

Similarly, 
$$R_{minimum} = -R_{maximum}$$

Moreover, 
$$\vec{r}_{maximum} = 0.5((T, 0) + (0, T)) \Rightarrow r_{maximum} = \frac{\sqrt{2}T}{2}$$

and, as before,

$$r_{minimum} = -r_{maximum}$$

Is this correct or did I fail something?

Comment: Your change of variables maps a rectangle in the $(x,y)$-plane to a rhombus in the $(r,R)$-plane, not a rectangle. You need more elaborate limits on your new integral. I suggest drawing a picture.

Comment: The correct limits for an inner integral, after a change of variables, are not the largest and smallest possible values that variable can take *ever*; they are the largest and smallest possible values that variable can take *given a particular value $r$ of the outer variable*. In particular, the limits of the inner integral usually are functions of $r$ (or whatever the outer variable is).